# ActivePresentation problem when trying to use Custom Layouts

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to make a macro to create Powerpoint presentations using Custom Layouts. Here's the code:

```
Sub PPT_Criar()
    Dim ppApp As Object
    Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim ppTextBox As PowerPoint.Shape
    Set ppApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Add
    ppPres.ApplyTemplate "D:\Users\11111\Documents\Modelos Personalizados do Office\PRES.potx"
    ppApp.Visible = True
    ppApp.Activate

    Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)
    ActivePresentation.Slides(1).CustomLayout = ActivePresentation.Designs(Theme2).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(3)

    ppSlide.Select

    Set ppTextBox = ppSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 0, 20, 100, 30)
    With ppTextBox.TextFrame2
        .TextRange.Text = EPS
        .TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
        .TextRange.Font.Size = 26
        .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
    End With
End Sub
```

When I run it, I get the error

> "run-time error '429' activex component can't create object"

in the `ActivePresentation` line. I've tried other ways to do it, and in all of them I get the same error where the `ActivePresentation` is.

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Don't use `ActivePresentation` - use `ppPres`, right? Or `ppSlide`? You've also got a mix of early and late binding. I'd suggest that you be consistent.